# Difference between `int (*B)[COLSIZE];` and `int *C[ROWSIZE];`?

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between the following declarations?

```
int (*B)[COLSIZE];
int *C[ROWSIZE];

B = (int (*)[COLSIZE])malloc(ROWSIZE * sizeof(int[COLSIZE]));
for (int i=0; i &lt; ROWSIZE; ++i)
    C[i] = (int *)malloc(COLSIZE * sizeof(int));
```

I understand that both are different ways to declare a 2-D array. But I cannot figure out the difference between the two. Any pictorial explanation will be much appreciated.

Comment: When you have difficulty understanding a C declaration try using http://cdecl.org.

Comment: @PaulR +1 That is one useful link!

Comment: I highly recommend a classical paper by Andrew Koenig which has helped me tremendously in the past: http://www.literateprogramming.com/ctraps.pdf

Answer (score 3):

`B` is a pointer to an array of `COLSIZE` `int`s, which in this context is being used as an array. It is being used to `malloc` a *contiguous* array of `ROWSIZE` x `COLSIZE` ints.

`C` is an array of `ROWSIZE` pointers to `int`. It is being used to malloc `ROWSIZE` x `COLSIZE` array of `int`s, but the rows are *not* contiguous - each row is actually a separate 1D array.

In either case the elements can be addressed as `B[i][j]` or `C[i][j]`, but the underyling data organisation is different.

When you access `B[i][j]` a simple index calculation is performed (the "flattened" index is `i * COLSIZE + j`).

When you access `C[i][j]` the pointer `C[i]` is first loaded as the base address for row `i`, and then the `j`th element of this row is located by adding offset `j` to this base address.